# SQL - 1. Round the difference to 2 decimal places

Tags: sql, oracle, decimal, rounding

I am trying to create an SQL statement with a subquery in the SELECT attribute list to show the product id, the current price and the difference between the current price and the overall average.

I know that using the ROUND function will round the difference to zero decimals but I want to round the difference to 2 decimal places.

```
SELECT p_code, p_price, ROUND(p_price - (SELECT AVG(p_price) FROM product)) AS "Difference" 
FROM product;
```

I tried using CAST but it still gave me the same output.

```
SELECT p_code, p_price, CAST(ROUND(p_price - (SELECT AVG(p_price) FROM Lab6_Product)) as numeric(10,2)) AS "Difference" 
FROM lab6_product;
```

Thank you in advance for your time and help!

Comment: Have you tried ROUND((p_price - (SELECT AVG(p_price) FROM Lab6_Product), 2) ?

Comment: Rookie mistake in your question: I am trying to create an SQL statement (OK so far!) **with a subquery <etc.>** The rookie mistake is to include your attempted solution as part of the requirement. The requirement is to display code, price and difference from average, in whatever format; the problem statement **does not** include **how** to do it (with a subquery or in any other way). In this case the best answer does NOT use a subquery, but the analytic version of AVG(), as in Gordon's answer. That way you only go once over the input rows. With a subquery you read the table twice.

Answer (score 1):

`round()` takes a second argument:

```
SELECT p_code, p_price,
       ROUND(p_price - AVG(p_price) OVER (), 2) AS "Difference"
FROM product;
```

Note that I also changed the subquery to a window function.

I often recommend converting to a `number` or `decimal`/`numeric`) instead:

```
SELECT p_code, p_price,
       cast(p_price - AVG(p_price) OVER () as number(10, 2)) AS "Difference"
FROM product;
```

This ensures that the two decimal points are displayed as well.

Comment: +1 for using analytic version of AVG() - that is the right approach. Please note though that CAST does not affect DISPLAYING of anything; `select cast(10 as number(10,2)) from dual` still displays `10` and not `10.` or `10.00` (not sure what you meant by "the two **decimal points** are displayed).

Comment: @mathguy . . . I would think most tools that display results would follow the types of the columns.  I can't speak for every tool, but many do.

Comment: I don't know about "most tools", but I will venture to guess that at least 70% of Oracle practitioners use SQL\*Plus, Toad, or SQL Developer. All three display 10.00 as 10 - whether you `select col from tbl` and `col` is data type `NUMBER(10,2)` or you `select cast(10 as number(6, 2)) from dual`. So, I would say the answer to that is "NO".

Comment: It is also unclear why formatting should matter in this question anyway; the OP asked about ROUNDING, so 9.37 is not rounded to 9. I don't know (there is nothing in the original question to suggest it) if the OP cares between 9 and 9.00.

Comment: @mathguy . . . Usually, when someone wants a rounded value, they don't want to see `9.370000`.

Comment: I don’t see the connection. Where in the original post, or anywhere else, did the OP mention anything about the optional trailing zeros?